# For in layouts files

Tags: android

On my app when you unlock it, a database connection is opened and i download a logo from a url, dynamically.

how to run over the layouts files to set this bitmap on every imageview?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ???; i++) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("logo", "id", getPackageName());
        if(id != 0) {
           ImageView imageView = findViewById(id);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);    
        }                       
}
```

all id's in every view is "logo", but they are in different files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive method to scan the entire view hierarchy, as long as you have a reference to the root view.

```
private void updateAllImages(View v) {
    if (v instanceof ImageView) {
        ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) v;

        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            updateAllImages(group.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This method accepts any view and then:

- if it is an `ImageView`, sets the image bitmap
- if it is a `ViewGroup`, calls itself for each child

When you pass the root view of your view tree to this method, it will wind up scanning the entire tree and updating every ImageView it finds.

If you have some ImageViews that you **don't** want to have updated, then you can add some logic around that as well. You mentioned that every view you want to update has the `logo` id, so you could check that:

```
private void updateAllImages(View v) {
    if (v instanceof ImageView && v.getId() == R.id.logo) {
        ((ImageView) v).setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) v;

        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            updateAllImages(group.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but this is only in one "layout.xml" no? i was thinking if don't have a way to, as long i have the image downloaded, run a search over the whole project layout files. To change of screen i use intents and not setContentView.

Comment: Correct, this will only affect any ImageView that's in the same view tree as whatever you pass to it, so it will only affect one activity at a time. There's nothing stopping you, though, from creating a "base" activity that all your other activities extend from and then doing this in `onPostCreate()` or similar (so that you don't have to write it in every activity subclass).